# Getting the top highest result from a set with MDX

Tags: mdx

I need to get the top 50 sellers names per State from the cube

this is what I have so far

```
SELECT NON EMPTY ( [DimGeo].[State].[State].ALLMEMBERS *
[Measures].[Total Sales]) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY TOPCOUNT([DimEmployee].[Employee ID].[EmployeeID].MEMBERS,50,[Measures].[Total  Sales]) ON ROWS
FROM Sales
```

But this only gets 50 results (even if an state doesn't have 50 results). I want to limit the State results by the 50 non empty highest values.

Example: The final table will have 2500 results (top 50 reseller per 50 states).

Is there a way I could achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're looking for the [Generate()](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Generate.html) function:

```
SELECT 
   NON EMPTY ( [Measures].[Total Sales]) ON COLUMNS, 
   NON EMPTY Generate( [DimGeo].[State].[State].ALLMEMBERS as s,
             TOPCOUNT(s.currentMember * [DimEmployee].[Employee ID].[EmployeeID].MEMBERS, 50, [Measures].[Total  Sales] )) 
ON ROWS FROM fdmdw
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, that's a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you, by moving the State to the Rows Level?

```
SELECT NON EMPTY ( [Measures].[Total Sales]) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY ([DimGeo].[State].[State].ALLMEMBERS  * TOPCOUNT([DimEmployee].[Employee ID].[EmployeeID].MEMBERS,50,[Measures].[Total  Sales])) ON ROWS
FROM fdmdw
```

Comment: I tried this before, but it just gets me the top 50 results among all of the States and not the 50 top sales per state.